# Can abdominal muscles take over 75% of the workload of a diaphragm and restore 100% lung function?

Tags: medical-science

[This News Report](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/ahmedabad/Six-pack-abs-helped-him-breathe-for-life/articleshow/47377512.cms) says that the boy mentioned had 75% of his diaphragm removed due to cancer, however as a result of strong abdominal muscles now has 100% lung function.

Is this really feasible, or is this the media exaggerating, since after all, breathing is not the primary function of abdominal muscles, so reaching 100% on them seems odd...

Comment: define "100% function". The ability to breathe seems plausible, especially with the 25% of diaphragm still in place.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) What would you consider an acceptable answer to look like (in either direction)?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think a lung function of 100% would mean perfectly functioning lungs right?

Comment: @Oddthinking An acceptable answer would link to a study or some sort of reliable\academic source for abdominal muscles taking up the role of the diaphragm or something on those ines

Comment: "Perfectly functioning" is no meaningful medical category. There are literature values of how much lung function a man of a certain age, weight and height should have. If he should have 5 liter vital capacity and he has 5,5 liter vital capacity that's 110%. If he has 4,5 liter that's 90%. The guy in question might very well have had more than 100% before the operation.